# How to avoid form submission in case of error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the form like below

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" class="collapse in">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- form fields are here -->
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="search" name="search" data-loading-text="Searching...">Search</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>    
</form>
```

And I use the following code to act once button is pressed:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    try {
        // some javascript with syntax error is here
    } finally {
        return false; // don't submit form automatically
    }
});
```

But if my javascript contains syntax errors, then the form is submitted regardless of `try .. finally`. How can I fix that? The form should be never submitted automatically.

Comment: Don't you have a development/QA environment where you would test the JavaScript first for syntax errors?  Syntax errors should never go into production because they can be immediately caught every time.

Comment: Test your sanitation/error checking function on a button that isn't the submit?

Comment: Other than js,you can use ajax .$.ajax({ error:function(){ whatever },success:function(your code on success)}).Moreover,you can also use beforesend:function(){which you want to confirm..if not,return false}.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the button type to "button".

> button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side
>   scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when
>   the events occur.

```
<button type="button"...>Search</button>
```

The form won't submit at all if that is the case until you tell it to explicitly submit via Javascript.

See HTML5 specs for this simple solution. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type

Comment: Do not use an empty action attribute. It violates HTML5 specs. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-action . And to answer your question, yes, setting action = "" will submit the form but to your current context page.

Answer (score 2):

Set the action of the form to something that isn't correct, like `action="error.html"`.  Then as the final step in the form submit process, dynamically set the action to the correct link.

You can also make the button not submit at all, and submit the form manually:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Comment: Will not `action=""` mean that the form should be POSTed to the same url?

Comment: @LA_: Good question.  It might, I'm not sure.  Maybe a better thing would be to actually submit the form manually.  So make it not a submit button, and then call `$('#myform').submit()` at the end of your code.  Or you could have the default post location some error page like `"error.html"`, then if the user arrives there, you know there was a JavaScript error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault` at the beginning of the event and trigger the submit yourself.

```
$("#search").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // some javascript with syntax error is here
    var foo = "bar";
    alert(foobar); // ERROR
    // if syntax error occurs in this scope, the form won't submit
    $(this).closest("form")[0].submit(); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VsS4z/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#search").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
try {
    // some javascript with syntax error is here
} finally {
    return false; // don't submit form automatically
}});
```

on the click function, prevent the default action.  Then if the code does pass, then manually call the submit

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```